# kubernetes node was low on resource: nodefsInodes

Tags: kubernetes

My kube-dns service on Kubernetes occasionally fails with the error:

```
The node was low on resource: nodefsInodes.
```

This tends to happen when I deploy 6 deployments all in one go.
I know what inodes are in a file system - but why would this happen?
My Docker images are using https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker.